# Declare font in math mode

Tags: math-mode, unicode, math-fonts

How I make the default font in math mode has nothing to do with `\setmainfont{some font}`.

Why is the character specified by `\it` **Times New Roman** and the others are **Computer Modern**?

Now I want to change **\it** font which in math mode to Computer Roman.

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
${v}_v＝{\it v}_0$，$x＝{\textit v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$
\end{document}
```

Patch Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
    range={"1D70B, "2605, "2ACB, "2AFD, "23DC}
]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={"221A, "221B, "221C}]
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}[range={"03C0}]
\setmathfont{XITSMath-Regular}
[
Extension = .otf,
BoldFont = XITSMath-Bold,
range={"2A00-"2AFF}
]
\begin{document}

${v}_v＝\mathit{v}_0$，$x＝\textit{v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an example to clarify your question, `\setmainfont{some font}` does not change the main math fonts, however the `[no-math]` option to `fontspec` stops it changing math at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle patch

Comment: (a) never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex (b) don't use `\it` with latex (although `\mathit{v}` would be the same (c) use `[no-math]` as noted above

Answer (score 2):

Never use T1 encoding with lualatex or xelatex.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
${v}_v＝{\it v}_0$，$x＝{\textit v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$
\end{document}
```

Here `{v}_v` use computer modern math italic

`{\it v}` which should be `\mathit{v}` uses Times Roman Italic

`{\textit v}` which should be `\textit{v}` uses Times Roman Italic

add `[no-math]` then all but textit use the cm math fonts.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
${v}_v＝\mathit{v}_0$，$x＝\textit{v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$
\end{document}
```

Note you are using  ， U+ff0c FULLWIDTH COMMA which is not in most latin fonts, use a normal ascii `,`  similarly use = not U+ff1d FULLWIDTH EQUALS SIGN

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}


${v}_v=\mathit{v}_0$, $x=\textit{v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your edited question shows using Stix Two mostly, but wanting to revert to Computer Modern locally. Here I set up an `lm` math version which is the default cm-style math font used by `unicode-math` but here just loaded in `lm` version.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont[version=lm]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}


${v}_v=\mathit{v}_0$, $x=\textit{v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$

{\mathversion{lm}


${v}_v=\mathit{v}_0$, $x=\textit{v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use xelatex,so can i use T1 encoding?

Comment: @Mahsatshak no xetex the advice is even stronger. T1 completely breaks xelatex hyphenation

Comment: The prologue has defined **mathfont**, but I want to make mathfont **Computer Modern** in some specific places temporarily. I added new patch in example.

Comment: @Mahsatshak how could you have expected anyone to ever have guessed that from your original question which had no code at all????? I'll add something

Comment: @Mahsatshak done

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. The later patch is based on your first answer to find out the problem. It is not that I deliberately concealed part of the code. I am very sorry about that

Comment: Unfortunately, such an error was reported: Package fontspec Error: ```The font "Latin Modern Math" cannot be found. \setmathfont.``` I used texlive2022 and did not add any parameters when applying fontspec.

Comment: @Mahsatshak use the  file name `\setmathfont[version=lm]{latinmodern-math.otf}` not the internal name if you have not set up xetex to find fonts by name.

Comment: It is worked. Thank you so much for your patience and sorry for my stupid way of asking.

Comment: I have a new doubt, can I add a patch to the ```\mathit{}``` directive to only use the fixed font instead of ```\setmathfont{}```

Comment: @Mahsatshak no really this is not how the site works, do not keep changing the question and adding new questions in comments. If you have a new question post a new question as otherwise this question/answer (which is archived here forever)  becomes impossible to understand